# Xubuntu doesn't have or allow for installation of software center

Tags: xubuntu, software-center, ruby

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 on an old dell tower I pulled out of my closet to use ruby on rails with.

I was attempting to install ruby and rails but none of the installs took. My system is updated and upgraded. I then tried to switch to ubuntu 15.04 but the terminal wouldn't allow for this either. I decided to change to ubuntu 15.04 through the software center but I couldn't find the software center. I tried to install it but the terminal out put the same as everything else, something like "can't find files".

I then realized after trying to search for the software center that it is on the drop down named as "\s\s\svb". When I try to run it I only get an alert stating "Failed to execute command "/usr/bin/software-center%u".

I have tried to download ubuntu 15.04 on my windows laptop and load it to a flash drive using unetbootin but It will not run on my tower. I can't upgrade desktops through the terminal, or apparently find or install any files. I can't access the software center either. I'm not very experienced with linux and I only want to learn ruby on rails which isn't something I am able to do very easily on windows. Any ideas or solutions would greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by  "but the terminal wouldn't allow for this either"? Please [edit] your post to include the exact error messages you got.

Answer (score 0):

To install Ruby On Rails, use this command

```
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Source: [Ubuntu Documentation for Ruby On Rails](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ruby-on-rails.html)